# Angular2. Animating left to right movement

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have an element that moves from left to right and back depending on a flag: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/criEdlaSfDmH5tzYo2h8?p=preview).
Now I want to add an animation to it. I tried to do it in most obvious way:

```
animations: [
    trigger('state', [
        state('true', style({
            right: '10px',
        })),
        state('false', style({
            left: '10px',
        })),
        transition('* => *', animate('250ms')),
    ]),
],
```

It works when moving from left to right but not in other way: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LvNXdaWo1V4SLeG3wjpY?p=preview).

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: It's tricky! trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with: instead of `right` use calculated `left` value:

```
    state('true', style({
        left: 'calc(100% - 200px - 10px)',
    })),
    state('false', style({
        left: '10px',
    })),
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vKnhUokjwsyAxqKPrgft?p=preview)